# Ubuntu and Red Hat? PHP files deployment

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, redhat

I have developed an application using PHP in **Ubuntu** XAMPP 1.7.4 environment. Now I'm going to deploy this in **Redhat 5 OS**. Is there any problem with file system?

What are the rules I have to follow for **Redhat5 OS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend more on their particular Apache/php config. Anything to do with the OS not be noticeably different.

Comment: Any problem with PHP file system

Comment: None that I know of, apart from local variations in php/apache config and the whims of whoever is Admin on the machine. Watch out for default code pages in the MySQL/Postgress config and the php.ini. If all are not set to "utf-8" life can get pretty miserable.